# How to set acl when copying files from GCS to AWS S3?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

We have scripts that are using gsutil "cp" command to copy files from GCS to AWS S3 buckets.  The problem is that the S3 bucket owner can not access those files, hence the need to set acl to "bucket-owner-full-control" when dropping files on S3. How can we do that with gsutil cp command?

Thanks,
Fere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsutil cp -p src dest` to preserve the source ACL.
Alternatively, you can set a canned ACL when copying by using `gsutil cp -a bucket-owner-full-control src dest`.

Comment: Thanks much for your help!